# Trigonometric identity (for two-soliton solution in SG)

Tags: trigonometry, integrable-systems

Context: I am studying the construction of the two-soliton solution of the Sine-Gordon equation. Following [this presentation](http://campus.usal.es/%7Empg/General/CuiabasG1.pdf), they obtain

\begin{align}
a_1\left[\sin\left(\frac{\phi_2+\phi_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\phi_4+\phi_3}{2}\right)\right]&=a_2\left[\sin\left(\frac{\phi_3+\phi_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\phi_4+\phi_2}{2}\right)\right]\\
\tan\left(\frac{\phi_4-\phi_1}{4}\right)&=\frac{a_1+a_2}{a_1-a_2}\tan\left(\frac{\phi_2-\phi_3}{4}\right).
\end{align}
**My question is trivial: I am unable to obtain the final trigonometric expression**, which - for completeness - is the same (trivial) identity below (1.62) in the following book of [C. Rogers - Bäcklund and Darboux Transformations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521012880)

[image]

Comment: Connected: http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Rapports/2600-2699/2631.pdf

Comment: @hyriusen Let us know if you can proceed according to the given hint.

Comment: @user, I made it. Key point was to write the difference of sines as a product and then everything was straightforward. I knew the sum-to-product formula, however, I wasn't able to identifty $\alpha$ and $\beta$ when $\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta)=2\sin\beta\cos\alpha$ in this case. Thank you very much.

Comment: @hyriusen Indeed I supposed that with this simple hint you could proceed easily. Obviously the two expressions are not completely equivalent since the first one works also for $\frac{\phi_4-\phi_1}{4}=\frac \pi 2+k\pi$ and $\frac{\phi_2-\phi_3}{4}=\frac \pi 2+k\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use [sum to product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) that is
$$\sin\left(\frac{\phi_2+\phi_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\phi_4+\phi_3}{2}\right)=\\=2\sin\left(\frac{\phi_2+\phi_1-\phi_4-\phi_3}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\phi_2+\phi_1+\phi_4+\phi_3}{4}\right)$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{\phi_3+\phi_1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\phi_4+\phi_2}{2}\right)=\\=2\sin\left(\frac{\phi_3+\phi_1-\phi_4-\phi_2}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\phi_2+\phi_1+\phi_4+\phi_3}{4}\right)$$

and proceeding form here cancelling out the two equal cosine terms and using that $\sin (A+B)=\sin A \cos B+\sin B \cos A$. All steps are elementary, just take the right conditions when dividing by the cosine terms.

Comment: "and proceeding _from_ here" : not evident...

Comment: It suffices continue with manipulation equating, cancelling cosine terms and using that $\sin (A+B)=\sin A \cos B+\sin B \cos A$. All steps are elementary, just taking the right conditions when dividing by the cosine terms. It is always good let some work to the asker, at least at the first step, in particular when any detail on their effort appears inthe question.